# Automatic AWeber Authentication? How do I access one user's data programmatically without them having to log in?

Tags: oauth, aweber

How can I use the AWeber API to automatically check whether an email address exists on a given user's list?  The AWeber paradigm is baffling to me and their docs are poor.  Essentially, what you get is the ability to put the AWeber login form on your site (just like this one: https://www.aweber.com/login.htm), so ANY AWeber user could use my site to log into their AWeber account and view their subscriber and list data.  This is useless.

The API keys are moot: they simply establish that yes, I am a developer and yes, I have registered my app.  The API keys have *nothing* to do with USER data.

This is not at all how MailChimp handles logins: each user can download their own API keys and use them to authenticate and then programmatically retrieve the subscriber data from their lists.

What I need to do is to create a "Members' Area" on my website, and in order for visitors to see the content in the members-only content, they must join my list.  It's a simplified login form that would ask only for the email address (no password is necessary).  But I cannot see how to do this with AWeber's convoluted oAuth restrictions.  The only way I can currently check email addresses is by logging into my own form (the local copy of the https://www.aweber.com/login.htm form) and then checking the email address.  That won't work programmatically.  If I can't automatically access subscriber data, then what's the point of the API?

How can I automate authentication so my application can retrieve subscriber information from my user's lists without me having to log in?

Comment: 2 years have passed but not even a single answer or a comment on this.

Comment: DId you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The consumer keys identify your application, the access keys are what give the application access to an account, both are needed to make requests to the API.

There is a php quickstart for accessing an aweber accounts' subscriber data. http://engineering.aweber.com/quick-start-api-script-in-php/
Once you have the access keys generated, you must store them for future requests.